# I am programming a text to binary program, but when I execute it it only prints one binary letter

Tags: python, binary

I am using python to create a text to binary translator, I checked everything and it seems alright but when I execute it, the program only prints the first letter of the text. Here's the code:

```
if beep == 1:
letter = letter + 1
if letter > length:
    beep = 2
if list1[letter] == "a":
    print abinary   
elif list1[letter] == "b":
    print bbinary

elif list1[letter] == "c":
    print cbinary

elif list1[letter] == "d":
    print dbinary

elif list1[letter] == "e":
    print ebinary

elif list1[letter] == "f":
    print fbinary
elif list1[letter] == "g":
    print gbinary
elif list1[letter] == "h":
    print hbinary
elif list1[letter] == "i":
    print ibinary
elif list1[letter] == "j":
    print jbinary
elif list1[letter] == "k":
    print kbinary
elif list1[letter] == "l":
    print lbinary
elif list1[letter] == "m":
    print mbinary
elif list1[letter] == "n":
    print nbinary
elif list1[letter] == "o":
    print obinary
elif list1[letter] == "p":
    print pbinary
elif list1[letter] == "q":
    print qbinary
elif list1[letter] == "r":
    print rbinary
elif list1[letter] == "s":
    print sbinary
elif list1[letter] == "t":
    print tbinary
elif list1[letter] == "u":
    print ubinary
elif list1[letter] == "v":
    print vbinary
elif list1[letter] == "w":
    print wbinary
elif list1[letter] == "x":
    print xbinary
elif list1[letter] == "y":
    print ybinary
elif list1[letter] == "z":
    print zbinary
else:
    print "error."
```

Anyone know what is going on, I am fairly knew but I cant find this in any of my books.

Comment: This is a basic problem that most if not all textbooks relating to programming would cover. You want to _repeat_ or _loop_ your logic for converting text to binary for each letter i.e. each element of your list.

Comment: How is this used? - oh and as a side, option, please use a dictionary instead of a if-elif chain.

Comment: None of this is inside a loop, so python only executes it for the first letter. Use a 'for' loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code to run multiple times, you need to use a loop:

```
while beep == 1:
     if list1[letter] == "a":
         print abinary

     ...
     letter = letter + 1
     if letter >= length(list):
          beep = 2
```

You can even do this more beautiful using a [for-loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) to iterate over all letters in your list:

```
for letter in list1:
    if letter == "a":
        print abinary
    ...
```

instead of chaining alot of elifs you should store the binary representation of the letters in a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
binary_letters = {
    "a": "01100001",
    "b": "01100010",
    ...
    "z": "01111010"
    }
```

this will simplify the loop to:

```
for letter in list1:
    print binary_letters[letter]
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop that you can implement it as follows, you can even convert the letters to a binary string:

```
letter="k"
for n in range(97,123):
    if ord(letter)<97 or ord(letter)>123:
        #if character is not between 97-123 (a-z) print an error message
        print("Error:Not in range")
        break
    #print(n)
    if n==ord(letter):
        #print the binary string if character is between the codes 97-123 (a-z)  
        print(format(ord(letter),'b'))
```